# How to make a dynamic regex in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've come up with a regex to match terms that contain a certain phrase, which can include letters or numbers, and excludes a dash. For instance, `test-123`, `test123` and `test` will all be matched by `^[test0-9._-]+$/gi`.

However, in MongoDB, I'm not too sure how to dynamically search for it. I've tried,

```
      const { search } = req.query;

      const regex = new RegExp(`/^[${search}0-9._-]+$/`, "ig");

      const results = await Test.find({ name: { $regex: regex } })
```

I've also tried

```
 await Test.find({ name: { $regex: ".*[" + search + "0-9._-]+$.*", $options: "i" } })
```

As well as just,

```
      const regex = new RegExp(`/^[${search}0-9._-]+$/`, "ig");

      await Test.find({ name: regex });
```

Not sure how to get this working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing `new RegExp(`/^[${search}0-9._-]+$/`, "ig")` returns following pattern `/\/^[test0-9._-]+$\//gi` which is probably not what you're trying to achieve (additional slashes).

You can try this way (tested in Mongo Shell):

```
let search = "test";
let regex = new RegExp(`^[${search}0-9._-]+$`, "ig");
db.test.find({ name: { $regex: regex } });
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:

You do not need to wrap the expression in "/" when using "new RegExp." Also, with expressions such as "\b" or anything with a backward slash, you may need to escape it with an extra "\"

For example:
const search = "string"
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${search}\\b`, "i");

Prints out:
/\bstring\b/i